# Automatically updating data across multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, rows, cells

I'm trying to create an excel workbook where updates to a master spreadsheet will be automatically reflected onto worksheets within the same workbook which derive from filtered data from the master spreadsheet.

I tried resolving this issue by creating links between rows from the master spreadsheet to the derivative worksheets. Since they are tables, however, they will constantly be filtered which I have discovered breaks the links. Since the links were row-dependent, I cannot think of a way to be able to link all of them without constant breaks. Is there a way around this issue despite the fact that there are many variables at play?

Comment: Your question is way too broad. You may want to re-think your data architecture. Duplicating data from one spreadsheet to others is not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using PivotTables.

Drag all relevant fields to the row area (turn off all (sub-)totals) and the field you wish to filter for as the page filter.

Select the Options dropdown on the Pivot table Analyze contextual ribbon tab and choose "Show report filter pages".